# Find, count words in a document by first letter Java

Tags: java

I have txt file(

```
aaayyy,qqqqwwwww
sswwww,qqswddfed
swssaa,deedddddd
dsssss,deeffcccc
sssddd,deessaaaa
ddddss,qqwwedfvv
qwwwsd,qqddfffff
ddffff,wwedddddd
sddsss,qqqdddddd
```

) in which I want to find, count all words that begin with the same characters(all words start with `qq = qqqqwwwww,qqswddfed,qqwwedfvv .... .` ) and output save in new.txt with qq=5.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String searchWord = "aaayyy";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/test.txt"));
    byte[] content = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(content);
    fis.close();
    String[] lines = new String(content, "UTF-8").split(",");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split(",//n");
        int j=1;
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(searchWord)) {
                System.out.println("find word = " +j);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here, the code which only find a word in the document, i know this code is not good. if you have a completely different solution, please write. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `firstletter`? Is `qq` a first letter? What encoding do you use?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What is your issue? That it only finds one word? You're looking for "aaayyy" and this is only a single time in the file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your `searchWord` variable is, but if this is the prefix you want to search all the words on then it is something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String searchWord = "aaayyy";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/test.txt"));
    byte[] content = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(content);
    fis.close();
    String[] lines = new String(content, "UTF-8").split(",");

    PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter("new.txt", "UTF-8"); //create writer for your new.txt

    int amountFound = 0; //amount of times the word started with searchWord

    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split(",//n");

        for (String word : words) {
            if (word.startsWith(searchWord)) { //check if word starts with searchWord
                amountFound++;
            }

        }
        writer.println(searchWord + "="+amountFound);
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

If you want to check for **all** the words instead of just the `searchWord`, let me know, I'll try to edit my answer if I can find the solution.

Comment: this will write `aaayy=2` for example to `new.txt` **note**: it overwrites the file every time

Answer (score 2):

From what i understand, you have a .txt file with comma-seperated words and newlines, and you want to count the amount of words that starts with a given searchword, aye?

This code should do the trick:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String searchWord = "qq";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("./words.txt"));
    byte[] content = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(content);
    fis.close();
    String[] lines = new String(content, "UTF-8").split(",");
    ArrayList<String> wordRes = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split("\n");
        for (String word : words) {
            if(word.startsWith(searchWord)) {
                wordRes.add(word);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total words beginnig with '" + searchWord + "': " + wordRes.size());
}
```

If you wish to find all words in the .txt file that contains the searchWord, then simply change this:

```
            if(word.startsWith(searchWord))
```

to

```
            if(word.contains(searchWord))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try my solution

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("1.txt"));
    int n = 0;
    while(sc.findWithinHorizon("\\bqq", 0) != null) {
        n++;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: Shouldn't a 78k reputation user know that "try my solution" isn't a proper answer description? Please add a proper explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Halim
 */
public class CountWords {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String searchWord = "aa";
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("./words.txt"));
    byte[] content = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(content);
    fis.close();
    String[] lines = new String(content, "UTF-8").split(",");
    ArrayList<String> wordRes = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split("\n");
        for (String word : words) {
            if(word.startsWith(searchWord)) {
                wordRes.add(word);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total words beginnig with '" + searchWord + "': " + wordRes.size());
     System.out.println("word are "+wordRes);
}   
}
```